# Terraform to define different module source based on a condition that is based on a nested json data

Tags: terraform, hcl

I have a nested json data that I have flattened it and want to call different module basing on the variable value while looping through that flattened variable  . How can I achieve it ?

below is the json and the module block that we are using

```
      “customMetric” = “true”,
      “env” = “prod”,
      “service_name” = “cat-v1",
      “app_name” = “cat-v1",
      “qma_app_name” = “cat-v1",
      “host_count_metric_name” = “uptime”,
      “request_trend_metric_name” = “requests.count”,
      “error_5xx_request_metric_name” = “requests.count”,
      “error_5xx_response_metric_name” = “response_code”,
      “error_4xx_request_metric_name” = “requests.count”,
      “error_4xx_response_metric_name” = “response_code”
},
{
      “customMetric” = “false”,
      “env” = “prod”,
      “service_name” = “cat-v2",
      “app_name” = “cat-v2",
      “qma_app_name” = “cat-v2",
      “host_count_metric_name” = “uptime”,
      “request_trend_metric_name” = “requests.count”,
      “error_5xx_request_metric_name” = “requests.count”,
      “error_5xx_response_metric_name” = “response_code”,
      “error_4xx_request_metric_name” = “requests.count”,
      “error_4xx_response_metric_name” = “response_code”
     }
{
      “customMetric” = “true”,
      “env” = “prod”,
      “service_name” = “cat-v2",
      “app_name” = “cat-v2",
      “qma_app_name” = “cat-v2",
      “host_count_metric_name” = “uptime”,
      “request_trend_metric_name” = “requests.count”,
      “error_5xx_request_metric_name” = “requests.count”,
      “error_5xx_response_metric_name” = “response_code”,
      “error_4xx_request_metric_name” = “requests.count”,
      “error_4xx_response_metric_name” = “response_code”
     }
]
```

```
module “example” {
  for_each                   = local.services
  source                      = “${each.value.hasCustomMetric}” == “true” ? “/path1" : "/path2"
  team_name                   = each.value.team_name
}
```

Comment: Are there any errors? If so, add them to the question if possible.

Comment: I'm pretty sure module source is not allowed to be a dynamic value. That's just not a feature supported by Terraform.

Comment: Yeah , Since module source is not allowed to be a dynamic value , I am not sure what to do and its a nested variable that it needs to loop on so need to find a way